# How to get information about all account nos from Aria using only one API call

Tags: system, aggregate, billing, api-design

Aria is a third party billing system. There is an API provided for accessing information stored at Aria by providing some credentials. For a particular credential, there are no. of accounts associated. In almost all of the API functions that Aria has provided require account no. as one of the parameters. So, my problem is that I have to get the information about all the accounts for a particular credential in one API call without specifying any account no. We can assume that no. of accounts are less than 400.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string escaping technique, such as:

```
?accountno=name'%20OR%20'a'='a
```

**References**

- [Fuzzing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Fuzzing)
- [Ajax and Other "Rich" Interface Technologies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Ajax_and_Other_%22Rich%22_Interface_Technologies)
- [Web Services](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Services)
- [Testing for Stack Overflow](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Stack_Overflow)

Comment: I fetched the required information by making use of **query_string=acct_no%20!%3D%200%3E** i.e. **acct_no != 0**.